# Money type column to char

Tags: sql, sql-server, char, case, currency

```
CASE
 WHEN actual = 'NULL' THEN 0
 ELSE actual
END AS Cost
```

'Actual' column -> money, 'Cost' column -> char/text

If there's any 'NULL' in 'actual', I wanna change it to 0.00 to 'Cost'

And how to CONCATENATE (in Excel function) it in SQL, so the value in 'Cost' will become Rp [value].00?

Error said :

> *Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect
>   syntax*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NULL` check appears to be off -- use `IS NULL` instead of `= 'NULL'`:

```
CASE WHEN actual IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE actual END AS Cost
```

Comment: @anakpanti -- np, glad I could help!

Comment: it works.. thx a lot. and how about the Concatenate? do you think it's possible to make it like -> Rp 0.00 ?